# Install SQL Server 2014 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sql-server-2014

I have recently upgraded my laptop to use Windows 10 home edition, now I am trying to install SQL Server 2014 evaluation server.

Failed installation at "Restart required", no need to say I have restarted the operating system many times.

Another problem that I am facing is installation won't complete, it got stuck at middle of the installation process.

[image]

Any ideas on solving this problem ?

Comment: any error in setup log files (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) or SQL Server error logs ( Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.XXXX \MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG) ?

Comment: Additionally, check to see if you have orphaned pending file moves or renames in the registry HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager (look for PendingFileRenameOperations). You can also use the pendmove tool from sysinternals (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556). Windows update can sometimes cause this also. Look in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\AutoUpdate and see if there's a RebootRequired key. Adobe updater has also been known to cause this problem and that can be solved by disabling the service